# Is Dyson Series a unitary operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory, approximations, unitarity

I am currently study time dependent perturbation theory. If I understand correctly Dyson series help us to approximate time evolution of initial state.

However, I am confused about the case when we want to solve for the amplitude of the unchanged state.

In this case, the first coefficient is $c_n^{0} = 1$ the second coefficient is complex number. Does that mean the coefficient of the unchanged state is amplified? And does that mean the amplitude do not conserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unitarity is a non-linear property. It is therefore too much to expect that unitarity will hold at each order in perturbation theory.

Consider a complex number $z = \cos(\phi) + \mathrm i \sin(\phi)$. Obviously, $|z|^2 = 1$, but for small $\phi$ we have $z \simeq 1 + \mathrm i \phi$, which has an absolute value larger than $1$. Something very similar happens when we expand a unitary operator, for example as a Dyson series.

If unitarity is important, one can consider using a [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion) instead. The idea is to formally write $U = \mathrm e^{\mathrm i X}$ for some Hermitian $X$ and expand $X$ instead of $U$. Since hermitianity is a linear property, it will hold order for order in perturbation theory (and therefore also the unitarity of $U$). Doing this expansion is a lot more difficult in practice, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. The example is really helpful. I don't know much about the application. Is there any case that unitary must be consider? For example, in very large scale?

Comment: In numerical simulations for example, one also had to truncate the time evolution operator, but to preserve the norm you want a unitary operator. Do instead of just taking the say first order expansion $1+itH$ you'd like use something more involved like the Crank-Nicholson or Strang-Splitting schemes.